# How to disable Toasts in an Activity

Tags: android

is it possible to disable all Toasts in an Activity? I use an Library which displays toasts on every start. This is getting annoying for some users of my app. Is it possible to force Toasts to disable?

thank you.

Comment: How about disabling the library's toasts instead? Which library are you using? Perhaps it's configurable.

Comment: I can't do it unfortunately... (its a .jar file...I have no Idea how the Library creats the toasts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but there is no way for you to disable the display of `Toasts`, other than to get the source code to your JAR, remove them at the source level, and rebuild the JAR.